# Regarding AlertDialog Box

Tags: android, exception

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnDoubleTapListener,OnGestureListener
    {
        GestureDetector detector;
            @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
           detector = new GestureDetector(this, this);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
            if(e.getAction()==1)
            {
            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "onDoubleTap", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    getApplicationContext());

                // set title
                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your Title");

                // set dialog message
                alertDialogBuilder
                    .setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                            // if this button is clicked, close
                            // current activity
                            MainActivity.this.finish();
                        }
                      })
                    .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                            // if this button is clicked, just close
                            // the dialog box and do nothing
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

                    // create alert dialog
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                    // show it
                    alertDialog.show();
                }

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
            if(e.getAction()==1)
            {
           // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "onDoubleTapEventOccursAgainAndAgain", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    getApplicationContext());

                // set title
                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your Title");

                // set dialog message
                alertDialogBuilder
                    .setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                            // if this button is clicked, close
                            // current activity
                            MainActivity.this.finish();
                        }
                      })
                    .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                            // if this button is clicked, just close
                            // the dialog box and do nothing
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

                    // create alert dialog
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                    // show it
                    alertDialog.show();
                }



            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
            if(e.getAction()==1)
            {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "onSingleTapConfirmed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                float velocityY) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
                float distanceY) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            return detector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    }
```

In this i want to create alert dialog box when i double click on android screen.But i found the following error:

```
06-03 11:26:13.321: E/AndroidRuntime(12824): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-03 11:26:13.321: E/AndroidRuntime(12824): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try replacing...

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
```

with this

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
```

as i cannot see the remainder of your logcat, i'm guessing this is the error.

Comment: On a side note, you should almost always use the Activity context, not the Application context.

Comment: ok thanks..and i am using listView in the linear layout.So when i double click on that it doesnot show the alert dialog box,while on a simple layout it gives me an alert dialog box??

Comment: that sounds about right. basically it depends on how you code the selection of a `ListView` row. I'm not sure how you would implement a double-click of a `ListView` row...i haven't done that myself (yet?)

Comment: @DavidM ok..actually i just want to show toast when i click on the lisview or autocomplete text view.Because when i make a click on the linear layout,it gives me a toast but when on the list view or auto complete text view,it doesnot gives toast?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
```

into

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivityName.this);
```